# Webserver attack solutions?

Tags: linux, apache, debian

I own an Apache webserver on a Debian 8 VPS, and i got errors like this in my error log 
What kind of attack is that? Is there any solution against?

```
[Sat Feb 02 07:05:49.618301 2019] [:error] [pid 7679] [client RANDOM_IP_ADDRESS:58746] script '/var/www/html/info1.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Feb 02 07:05:49.876335 2019] [:error] [pid 7679] [client RANDOM_IP_ADDRESS:58746] script '/var/www/html/aaaaaa1.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Feb 02 07:05:50.134024 2019] [:error] [pid 7679] [client RANDOM_IP_ADDRESS:58746] script '/var/www/html/up.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Feb 02 07:05:50.392310 2019] [:error] [pid 7679] [client RANDOM_IP_ADDRESS:58746] script '/var/www/html/test123.php' not found or unable to stat
```

(and other 300+ errors with random path)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Probably looking for exploitable scripts, perhaps that take GET arguments, etc. to maybe do a mysql injection or something.

Since it is your VPS, you could do something like install/configure `fail2ban` and have it watch for excessive 404 errors from a specific IP, at which point it will block it via `iptables`